# Symfony RememberMe token_provider

Tags: symfony, silex, symfony-security

I'm building an app with silex and I'm using the built-in SecurityServiceProvider and I'm trying to use the rememberme service and I'm looking at the documentation and there a option called token_provider but symfony doesn't really state if that is a string or if its an instance of an object.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see a *token_provider* option on the documentation for the [*RembemberMe* Service](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/remember_me.html)

Comment: its because its listed on the symfony cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter is a *service id of a token provider to use*. Services id are strings (then Symfony looks for the class in the DIC, Silex does the same) so you need to declare a FQDN of your token provider class. [By default Symfony uses the *Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\RememberMe\InMemoryTokenProvider* class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security_rememberme.xml#L11)

If you want to create your own (probably you won't), you can take a look at [how Doctrine Project programed this service](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/RememberMe/DoctrineTokenProvider.php) by implementing the [TokenProviderInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/RememberMe/TokenProviderInterface.php).

Comment: I actually copied that as I'm using Laravel's Database ORM (since I'm comfortable with that) I just didn't knows how to set it.